# Hatte die Deutsche Sprache einst Adverbien wie im Englischen?

Tags: etymology, adjective, adverb

Gehe ich richtig in der Annahme, dass die deutsche Sprache einst die gleiche klare Trennung zwischen Adjektiv und Adverb besaß, wie sie heute noch im Englischen existiert (smooth, smooth**ly**)? Dass viele Adverbien zu Adjektiven wurden bzw. erhebliche Bedeutungsverschiebungen erfuhren? Aus dem noch verfügbaren Restbestand der Adjektiv-Adverb-Paare:

Adj.: gnädig Adv.: gnädig**lich** vgl. gracious, gracious**ly** 
Adj.: bitter Adv.: bitter**lich** vgl. bitter, bitter**ly** 
Adj.: sicher Adv.: sicher**lich** vgl. safe, safe**ly**
Adj.: frei Adv.: frei**lich** vgl. free, free**ly**
Adj.: klein Adj.: klein**lich** (früher Adv.?)

Adj.: süß Adj.: süß**lich** (früher kein Adv.?)
Adj.: gelb Adj.: gelb**lich** (früher kein Adv.?)

Dass es eine ähnliche Kreativität bei der Bildung von Adverbien gab wie heute im Englischen?

letzten Endes => letztend**lich** vgl. matter of fact => matter-of-fact**ly**
vermeinen/vermeint => vermein(-)t-**lich** (*t* Partizipendung oder Fugen-T?)
gelegen => gelegen-t-**lich** vgl. repeated => repeated**ly**⠀
⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wie fast immer ist es irreführend, vom Englischen auszugehen; außerdem ist die Darstellung der Situation im Englischen zu sehr vereinfacht. Das Phänomen, daß im heutigen Englisch die meisten Adverbien mit *-ly* abgeleitet sind, stellt keinen Urzustand dar, der verloren ging.

- Viele Adverbien sind nicht abgeleitet oder stammen nicht von Adjektiven: deutsch *oft, hier, heute, jetzt, immer …* – englisch *oft(en), here, today, now, always …*
- Die Ableitungen auf *-lich* (verwandt mit englisch *-ly*) können schon im Althochdeutschen Adjektive sein: *ärmlich, herrlich, fröhlich, rechtlich*. Auch im Englischen können sie Adjektive bilden: *a friendly man, a lovely day, our daily bread*.
- Ehemals hatten sowohl das Deutsche als auch das Englische mehrere Möglichkeiten, Adverbien zu bilden, zum Beispiel mittels einer Endung *-o/-e* (ahd. *herti – harto*, ae. *heard – hearde*). Daher (nach Wegfall der Endung) zum Beispiel bis heute als Adjektiv und Adverb *fest, lang, gern* – *fast, hard, quick* (*a fast train*, *the train moves fast*).
- Im Englischen wurde *-ly* im Lauf der Zeit populärer. So wurden einige ältere Adverbien ohne *-ly* durch jüngere Formen mit diesem Suffix ersetzt: *sooth – truly*; *sweet – sweetly* (Shakespeare: *How sweet the moon-light sleeps upon this bank!*).

  Das Deutsche dagegen bewahrte einerseits Adverbien auf *-e* (*feste, lange, gerne*) und unterscheidet andererseits Adjektiv und Adverb in vielen Fällen nicht (*er wartete lang*, *der Tag war lang*).

Zur Situation im Altenglischen siehe Sievers, [Angelsächsische Grammatik](https://archive.org/details/angelschsischegr00siev/page/168/mode/2up), § 315 ff. Für das Deutsche und Althochdeutsche habe ich im [DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB) und [AWB](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB) nachgeschlagen, z.B. [hart](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=hart), [herti](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=hart)/[harto](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=harto).

Comment: Ich finde diese Antwort eigentlich viel ausführlicher als die obigen Antworten, allerdings fehlt es an einer Quelle. Hast du eine Quelle, bei der ich nachlesen könnte?

Comment: Vielen Dank für die differenzierte Antwort. Ich hatte in der Tat irgendwie die adjektivische Verwendung im Englischen völlig aus den Augen verloren und bin so von einer vermeintlichen strikten Trennung ausgegangen, die es im Deutschen nicht mehr gibt. Im Englischen eben auch nicht - bis auf den häufigen und auffälligen Zwang der Adverbbildung mit _-ly_, anders als im Deutschen.

Comment: Deine Darsung ist aber auch irreführend. *ärmlich* dürfte vom Substantiv abgeleitet sein. Ich meine es gab sowas wie *Arme*. Das macht für die übliche Erklärung auch sinn, dernach *-lich* analog zu *Mannesgleich* zu verstehen wäre, dh. *manly*. *Fröhlich* dürfte direkt an ie. \*leyk- "to jump" anschließen, vgl. *froockend*. Scheint mir aber alles schon lange äußerst unsicher.

Answer (score 3):

Ja, es ist grundsätzlich richtig, dass früher im Deutschen (genauer gesagt im Mittelhochdeutschen) Adverbien durch einen Suffix gebildet wurden, ähnlich wie dies heute noch im Englischen der Fall ist.

> Ein Adverb wird aus einem Adjektiv durch das Anhängen von *-e* oder *-lîche* gebildet.
>
> Bsp.:
>
> *lanc–lange*,
>
> *hôch–hôhe*
>
> *sælec–sæleclîche*,
>
> *hövesch–höveschlîche*

Quelle: [Mittelhochdeutsche Kurzgrammatik](https://www.uni-frankfurt.de/47053276/Kurzgrammatik-HA_09_2009.pdf#page=33)

Comment: Hast du auch Infos über die Entwicklung der Verwendung so gebildeter Adverbien? Wann setzte die adjektivische Verwendung ein?

Answer (score 1):

### „einst sehr ähnlich“

Das zu hinterfragende Problem wird von Amanda Pounder direkt angesprochen (Hervorhebung meinerseits):

> […] if one goes back far enough, one finds that adverb-marking in the two languages was **once very similar**, and that indeed, the means of adverb-marking initially underwent parallel developments in the two languages. Indeed, **the affix *lich* was at one time used for the morphological marking of adverbs in German.**  [*Pounder, A. 2001*]

Als nachvollziehbares Beispiel steht da: *ein höflich unterdrückter Seufzer*, "a politely suppressed sigh" (pg. 301).

Zur Einordnung der Frage siehe bspw. eine Rezension der Adjektiv-Adverb-Abgrenzung im Deutschen:

> Claudia Telschow greift mit der Adjektiv-Adverb-Abgrenzung einen notorischen Aspekt der Wortartenforschung heraus, der schon häufig Gegenstand linguistischer Diskussionen war mit einer Reihe verschiedener Ergebnisse, die von den Extremen der Annahme zweier grundsätzlich voneinander zu trennenden Wortarten bis hin zu der Annahme reicht, dass Adjektive und Adverbien eine Wortart bilden (zur ersten Position siehe zum Beispiel Schmöe 2002, zur zweiten Position siehe Alexiadou 1997). [*Elsner, D. 2017, Review*]

Die Fragestellung ist also auch ein Problem der Interpretation. Dabei ist die Historik des Ableitungsmorphems gar nicht befriedigend, weil keine gesicherte indoeuropäische Etymologie für urgermanisch **līką* vorliegt. PIE **leyg-* ist eine rein mechanische Rekonstruktion, die nur im baltischen Sprachzweig zu Ergebnissen führt, womit die herkömmlichen Erklärung aus einem Wurzelnomen insoweit nicht bestätigt wird.

Doch geht Pounder glücklicher Weise nicht darauf ein und fasst die Situation hoch-deutsch wie folgt zusammen.

- Althochdeutsch *-o* bildet Adverben, vgl. bspw. *blint* "blind", *blinto* "blindly" (vgl. übrigens @DavidVogel, oben). Somit ist **adv. *-lihho*** von adj. *-lih* zu unterscheiden, wobei ein geringes Verwechslungs-Potential in der Beugung entsteht (pg. 303).
- Dann besteht Konkurenz zwischen *-o* und *-lihho* in der produktiven Bildung von Adverben, bspw. ahd. *ewigo* und *ewiglihho*, sodass sich *-lihho* herauslößt und anscheinend eigenständig Adverben wie *miltlihho* bildet, ohne ein soweit jedenfalls nicht bezeugtes *lih-adjektive* zum Vorbild zu nehmen (pg. 304).
- Nachdem Suffix *o* zu *e* [ə] abgeschwächt wird, ist das Verwechslungspotential im Übergang von Alt- zu Mittelhochdeutsch um so größer. Weiterhin soll Unterscheidung auf syntaktischer Ebene möglich sein (pg. 306).

  Ferner wird – wegen Lautwandel wie Umlautung – mit *enge / enge* < *engi / ango* eine fortschreitende Angleichung von ja-Stämmen an deren Adverbien verzeichnet, wodurch ein Anstieg der Suffix-Produktion zu *-lich* begünstigt würde (pg. 305).
- Während *-en* an *-lich* antritt, fällt *-e* außer Gebrauch:

  > *lich*, then, has become the principal suffix in any adverb-forming process that is overtly marked; the only alternative to lich-
  > suffixation is a zero-process whereby only the syntactic category and thus properties of the base are changed. [*Pounder, A. 2001, pg. 305*]

  Die darunter angeführten Beispiele (Pseudo-Magnus, 1581) wirken heute befremdlich, z.B.: "*und mit denselbigen ihren Henden /
  sol die Hebam **Senfftiglichen** greiffen zu der Mutter ...* (p.8f.)".

  Aus derselben Quelle ein Beispiel für Konversion ohne morphosyntaktische Markierung ("zero-process", pg. 305): "*so soll die Hebamm ... die schultern deß Kindts fleissig begreiffen ...* (p.11a)".

Im Artikel werden ferner die englischen Beispiele besprochen (pp. 306-8) sowie die Funktionen der Adverben in beiden Sprachen (308-15; 316-18) um anhand von Grammatiken der vorigen Jahrhunderte nach einem Grund für die letztendliche Veraltung der lich-Derivation zu suchen (319-50).

Schlussendlich stellt Pounder heraus, dass Standardisierung, die auch in westdeutsche Varietäten einzugreifen scheint (pg. 351), mittels einheitlicher Beugung der Adjektive und zunehmender Lexikalisierung der Suffixe die Unterscheidung von Adverben erleichtert hat ("The standardization of adjective inflection (*[...]*) was completely successful in the written standard and allowed for a complete local disambiguation from adverbs at the principal critical locus." pg. 352). Aber auch zunehmende Polemisierung wird erkannt und für das fortschreiten der Grammatik in eine unbestimmte Richtung erkannt.

#### „die gleiche klare Trennung zwischen Adjektiv und Adverb“

Die Frage ist hinreichend begründet, da die Annahme naheliegt, "dass die deutsche Sprache einst die gleiche klare Trennung zwischen Adjektiv und Adverb besaß, wie sie heute noch im Englischen existiert". Darunter wird auch klar, "Dass es eine ähnliche Kreativität bei der Bildung von Adverbien gab wie heute im Englischen?", und zwar so dass *Produktivität* definitionsgemäß nachweisbar ist, so bspw. mhd. *miltlihho* vs. engl. *mildly*.

Unterdessen ist nicht gesagt, inwieweit diese Ähnlichkeit auf eine gemeinsame Entwicklung zurückgeführt werden könnte oder doch Zufall sei.

#### Ad: *Miszäellige* Beispiele

Die zu vergleichenden Beispiele (OP) dürften teils dem Zufall zuzuschreiben sein.
Alle Angaben ohne Gewähr.

1. *Gnade, gnädig*, adv. *gnädiglich*, vgl. *eglesias* (von der Kirche), etwa *Gnade-*eglesis* entsprechend *von Gottes Gnaden*.
2. *Bitter, bitter*, adv. *bitterlich*, vgl. *beten, bitten*, behelfsweise mit *er-* (vgl. *ehrlich, erlauben*), *bitterlich weinen*.
3. *Security, sicherheit*, adv. *sicherlich*--bei Tom Gerhardt heißt det *sischer sischer*--vgl. *safe, safelock*; da will ich mich nicht festlegen, würde aber getrennte lombardische und fränkische Einflüsse unterstellen. Ebenso das folgende.
4. *Freiheit, frei*, adv. / interj. *freilich*--Ich bin ein Saupreuss doch glaube es heißt *freili*--vgl. *freien* "bitten", engl. *pray* "please" ("*pray tell*"); wegen der häufigen Verwendung wären verschiedentelliche Ursprünge denkbar, ...
5. *klein, kleinlich* (früher Adv.?) Bennecke (BMZ) nennt es *gracilis* und verweißt auf Diefenbachs Grammatik; Lexer unterscheidet adv. *klein-liche*: adv. *auf feine, zarte art. genau, kleinlîcher verstân* ([Lexer](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=Lexer&lemid=K01766#0)) also **ja, das ist ein generisches Adverb gewesen**. Ebenso das folgende. 6. *süß*, adj. *süßlich* (früher kein Adv.?) dito, und wie *bitterlich* auch als Geschmacksrichtung zu verorten, ist vielleicht Anschluss an onomatopoesia und synthestesia möglich, etwa interj. *lecker schmecker* (*süß-* ~). ... 7. *gelb*, adj. *gelblich* (früher kein Adv.?), vgl. *licht* oder ähnliches, falls ebenfalls imitativ im Sinne des vorigen; Im Sinne eines iterativem l-Suffix wäre eher an *vergilb(*l-)t* <sup>Sepia</sup> zu denken--an dieser Stelle wäre pejorativer Gebrauch aus der Semantik heraus zu erschließen.

---

### Literatur

Amanda V. Pounder. Adverb-marking in German and English: System and standardization.
in: Diachronica, Volume 18, Issue 2, Jan 2001, p. 301 - 358
DOI: https://doi.org/10.1075/dia.18.2.05pou

Daniela Elsner. Rezension: "Die Adjektiv-Adverb-Abgrenzung im Deutschen, von Claudio Telschow". in: Zeitschrift für Dialektologie und Linguistik, Bd. 84, H. 1 (2017), pp. 103-106. Literaturangaben:

- Alexiadou, Artemis (1997): Adverb Placement: a case study in antisymmetric syntax. Amsterdam: Benjamins (Linguistik Aktuell/Linguistics Today. 18).
- Bergenholtz, Henning/Burkhard Schaeder (1977): Die Wortarten des Deutschen. Versuch einer syntaktisch orientierten Klassifikation. Stuttgart: Klett.
- Pittner, Karin (2010): Prädikative Genitive - ein vernachlässigtes Kapitel der Grammatikschreibung. In: Deutsche Sprache 38 (3), 193-209.
- Rauh, Gisa (2010): Syntactic Categories. Their Identification and Description in Linguistic Theories. Oxford: Oxford University Press (Oxford Surveys in Syntax & Morphology).
- Schmöe, Friederike (2002): Die deutschen Adverbien als Wortklasse. [Unveröffentlichte Habilitationsschrift].
- Thieroff, Rolf/Petra Vogel (2012): Flexion. Zweite, aktualisierte Auflage. Heidelberg: Winter (Kurze Einführungen in die germanistische Linguistik. 7)

Answer (score 0):

Ich glaube, man müsste die Frage etwas splitten.

Was "gnädiglich" und "sicherlich" angeht, scheint es ein produktives adverbiales Affix "lîcho" gegeben zu haben (woerterbuchnetz.de):

- [gnädiglich](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG21296#XGG21296)
- [sicherlich](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS27371#XGS27371)

  In beiden Fällen scheint auch die adjektivische Verwendung sehr früh weggefallen oder gar kaum vorhanden gewesen zu sein. Für einige andere Fälle siehe Kommentar von @guidot an der Frage.

Comment: Hier musst du mich missverstanden haben. Ich meine nicht, dass aus _kleinlich_ (kompositionell) _klein_ (einfach) geworden ist. Das meinst du doch? Ich meine, dass zu der (zu beweisenden) ursprünglichen (ausschließlich _wie in EN_) adverbialen Verwendung von _kleinlich_ irgendwann auch eine adjektivische Verwendung hinzukam.

Comment: Ja, ich habe dich missverstanden, aber ich glaube trotzdem, dass die Frage nur differenziert nach einzelnen Wörtern beantwortet werden kann. Die Liste, die du aufstellst, ist etwas heterogen, wie @guidot schon geschrieben hat. In diesem Fall bliebe es zu beweisen, dass es ein Adverb wie "kleinlicho" existiert hat. Darüber ist bei den Grimms leider nichts zu finden.

Comment: @Nico: Kommentare sind nicht verlinkbar, Kommentare dürfen frei für eigene Antworten "geplündert" werden, da sie schneller verschwinden können als Antworten. Ich schlage vor, den relevanten Teil von guidots Kommentar zu inkludieren. Und von der verlinkten Quelle ebenfalls den relevanten Teil, der zur Antwort gehört. Andere Seiten können offline gehen, sagt die Hilfe.

Answer (score 0):

Teilantwort aus meinem vorigen Kommentar:

Einige Beispiele halte ich für eine ganz andere Konstruktion, die im Englischen mit *-ish* gebildet wird, wie *gelblich*: etwas ist nicht wirklich gelb, es geht nur in die Richtung.

Darunter fallen zumindest:

- süßlich
- gelblich
- ursprünglich wohl auch bitterlich, für das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bitterlich)  *ein wenig bitter* liefert; auch wenn heute meist mit *weinen* und *beklagen* verwendet.

Comment: Entscheidend für die Frage ist wohl die Verwendbarkeit als Adverb. Die ist bei _bitterlich_ offensichtlich gegeben. Dass sich diese aus einem gleich lautenden Adjektiv entwickelt hat, wage ich zu bezweifeln. Immerhin bedeutet _bitterlich weinen_ _"ordentlich" weinen_ und nicht nur _ein wenig weinen_, wie es zu verstehen wäre, wenn man die Definition des Adjektivs _ein wenig bitter_ heranzöge.

Comment: *bitterlich weinen* könnte durchaus wenig schrille Intensität bedeuten (sonst etwa *schluchzen*) aber frequentativ sein, vgl. bspw *trippeln*, *tippeln*, En *crackle*, *suckle*, ... dann mit *-ig* ~ *-ich* wie in *günstig*, *schaurig*, *ewig*, ... vielleicht eben deswegen klingen Konstruktionen wie *ewiglich* falsch konstruiert, immerhin gestelzt.