# Wieso hat sich "immer zu" zu "jetzt" entwickelt?

Tags: etymology

Laut dem [Etymologischen Wörterbuch](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/jetzt) stammt das Wort `jetzt` von den zwei Wörtern `immer` (*ie*) und `zu` (*zuo*) ab.

Weder `immer` noch `zu` sind für mich als Muttersprachler jedoch Wörter, die ich mit der *Gegenwart* in Verbindung bringen würde.

Wieso, oder aus welchem historischen Grund, haben sich also diese beiden Wörter in zusammengezogener Variante als Alternative zu `nun`, dem ursprünglichen Wort aus dem Proto-Indoeuropäischen, entwickelt?

Comment: Spannende Frage. Auch der Kluge spricht von einer "auffälligen Einschränkung der Bedeutung" und weiß nicht mehr liefern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Herkunftswörterbuch aus dem Duden-Verlag und [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jetzt) liefern im wesentlichen dieselbe Beschreibung der Abstammung.

Aber die Tatsache, dass ein Wort von einem anderen abstammt bedeutet ja noch lange nicht, dass diese Wörter dieselbe Bedeutung haben müssen. Man denke nur an vielen unterschiedlichen deutschen Wörter die vom indogermanischen *scei* (Bedeutung: schneiden, spalten, trennen) abstammen: *gescheit, Scheide, Scheidung, Scheitel, Scheiße, (Unter)schied, Schied(srichter) ...*

Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, ob das mittelhochdeutsche *»ie«* bzw. das althochdeutsche *»io«* bzw. *»eo«* tatsächlich als exakt gleichbedeutendes Synonym des modernen Wortes *»immer«* angesehen werden darf. Immerhin entstand das deutsche *»immer«* auch erst dadurch, dass *»ie«* mit dem Vorläufer des Steigerungswort *»mehr«* (*mēro; mēra; mēr*) zu *»iemēr«* verschmolz, aus dem später *»immer«* wurde.

Das mittelhochdeutsche *»ie«* ist nicht nur der direkte Vorläufer des modernen *»je«* (*»Warst du **je** dort?« »Das ergibt 100 Euro **je** Teilnehmer.« »**Je** mehr, desto besser.«*) sondern war - gemeinsam mit anderen Bestandteilen - auch eine Zutat bei der Entstehung der Wörter *»jeder«, »jemand«, »jeglich«.* Aber auch *»irgend«* (mittelhochdeutsch: *ieregen, ieregent,* althochdeutsch *io wergin*) geht darauf zurück. Das Wort *»ie«* scheint, wie ich glaube, für sich alleine also eher so etwas wie eine recht vage zeitliche oder kausale Ausdehnung zu beschreiben, und erst im Zusammenwirken mit anderen Wörtern ergab sich dann eine konkretere Bedeutung:

- ie + mer = je + mehr (also: mehr *je* = lange Zeit) = immer
- ie + zu = Konkretisierung von *je* = jetzt

Comment: Spannend zu sehen, dass _immer_ vermutlich auch ein zusammengezogenes Wort ist. Gibt es Quellen, welche die genaue Bedeutung des ursprünglichen _ie_ erklären?

Answer (score -1):

Auf dem Pfad der Zeit läuft man bildlich gesprochen **immer (weiter) zu**. Das ist eine denkbare Alternative zu **immer noch**, was so ziemlich gleichbedeutend mit **jetzt** ist. Echte Fakten wird dir keiner mehr liefern können, warum sich in ferner Vergangenheit dies und jenes durchgesetzt hat.

Answer (score -1):

Die Darstellung ist verkürzt. Gemeint ist, wenn man die Entwicklung weit genug zurückverfolgt und darauf andere Entwicklungsstränge nachvollzieht, kommt man bei *immer* und *zu* an.

Ob das stimmt oder ob *ie* (hic-et-nunc Partikel) und *zuo* anders erklärt werden müssten, sei vorerst dahingestellt. Weil, *immer zu* eine gangbare Adverbialphrase ist, quasi *allgegenwärtig*, ist die Erklärung dennoch einleuchtend. Wichtig ist an der Stelle für den historischen Sprachforscher erstmal nur, dass das Wort einzelsprachlich gebildet wurde und nicht auf eine ältere Muttersprache zurückgeht. Für den Geschichtsforscher ist die Grammatik wiederum relativ uninteressant. Ein einfaches Wörterbuch kann das jedenfalls nicht leisten.

Die einschlägige Wurzel in der gesuchten Bedeutung ist eigentlich in *nu'* erhalten, und es werden mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit Partikelketten auffindbar sein, die diese Worte in Zusammenhang bringen. Eine andere Partikel ist in *hier* und *heute* erkennbar; nach Verners Gesetz vermutlich auch das *ge-* in *gleich*, *von jetzt auf gleich*, sowie in *Gegenwart*.

*Zu* begegnet denn auch in *heutzutage*, vgl. En. *today*. Außerdem wird das *d'* in französisch *aujourd'hui* genauso erklärt.

Das muss jedoch zu einer weiteren Überlegung führen. *Tag* bzw. *day* kann nach lautgesetzlichen Regeln gerade nicht mit dem lateinisch *dies* "Tag" verwandt sein, das in der Bildung *hōc +‎ diē* (ablativ maskulin singular) "an diesem Tag" > altfranzösisch *hui* "heute" versteinert ist. Weil entsprechend hochdeutsch *z* < **d* gelten muss. Bleibt lediglich die Möglichkeit, *zu* könnte entsprechende Wortbedeutung erhalten haben. Dafür fehlen aber die Beweise.

---

Das deutsche kennt ja keine auf die Gegenwart beschränkte Zeitform (*ich gehe in die Schule* kann sowohl atelische als auch telisch sein), daher ergibt sich das nicht aus der Grammatik und ist pragmatisch zu bewerten. Z. B.:

> hiar hor er io zi guate, waz got imo gibiete, ... in frenkisga zungun O 1,1,121.

> [Althochdeutsches Wörterbuch: io I. 1. a) δ) *bei Konjunktiv Präsens, wünschend, in das Futurische weisend*]

Quasi: "Hier höre er ja gut zu, was Gott ihm gebietet". Dieses *ja* wird stark betont, ganz anders als *immer* bzw. *jetzt*. Dabei könnte *io* / *ja* aus der Endung des Subjunktivs hervorgegangen sein, Proto-West-Germanisch 3. Person singular subjunktiv präsens **hauʀijē*, imperativ **hauʀi*; der Plural des Imperativs **hauʀiþ* entspricht ebenso *hör(e)t* (en.WT: [*hauʀijan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/hau%CA%80ijan)).

Der Bezug zur Gegenwart besteht aber eindeutig wegen *hier*. Insoweit dies mit griechisch και verbunden wird (en.WT) fungiert es offenbar als Konjunktion, ist aber auch mit *her-hören* zu verwechseln, ἀκούω, *écouter*.

Weiter unten zu III. 6. **io zuo**

> a) *immer weiter, noch weiter*:

> > in dien dingen allen . sundoton sie ieo zuo

> > *in omnibus his peccaverunt a d h u c* Np 77,32"

> b) *bereits*:

> > iam (*Judas*) enim iudicatus erat

> > (**ioh was er iez** (Ausg. Piper Druckfehler, vgl. K.-T. 10,482 a, 22) verteilet) NpXgl 118 Cant. grad. (S. X,19; Npw De ps. gr. 5 sa)

> [o.c., fettdruck hervorhebung meinerseits]

Wem die lateinische Übersetzung nicht hilft, a) ... sie sündigten *immer fort*. b) zwischen den lateinischen und althochdeutschen Sätzen bestehen erhebliche Unterschiede, die nicht ohne weiteres zu erklären sind. Ich würde schlicht interpretieren: "so war er *halt*, der Judas"; "so war er *nunmal*".

Es fällt zwar auf, dass *iez* tatsächlich mit englisch *yet* "bereits" zu vergleichen ist (en.WT). Da englisch auslautendes -o sonst aber bewahrt bleibt (s. *into*), bestätigt das nur die Annahme oben, dass *zu(o)* hyperkorrekt ist. Der Vergleich mit *zi* (ebenso *fir-* in unbetonten Silben > *ver-*) bestätigt ferner den Vergleich oben mit *Ziu*. Da adv. *-e* einiger Schwankung unterlag (s. [Hatte die Deutsche Sprache einst Adverbien wie im Englischen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73610/35977)), ist die Annahme gerechtfertigt, dass *jetze* entscheidend zur Analogiebildung beigetragen hat.

*Jetz awer jenug*

---

Althochdeutsches Wörterbuch: [io](https://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemid=AI00646), [ioh](https://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&mode=Gliederung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=AI00672#XAI00672), [ja](https://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&mode=Gliederung&lemid=AJ00001#XAJ00001).

Comment: _Immer zu_ ist doch genau keine Adverbialphrase um das zeitliche _nun_ auszudrücken? Oder hast Du hierfür ein Gegenbeispiel?

Comment: Das habe ich nie so direkt behauptet. Aber natürlich schließt der Ausdruck immer zu die Gegenwart mit ein, und die Negation ist ggf. dann erfüllt, wenn das Argument in der Gegenwart gerade nicht zutrifft.