# Why längst nicht mehr?

Tags: phrase

What is the difference between

> nicht mehr

or

> lange nicht mehr

and

> längst nicht mehr?

From DWDS:

> Ich habe **längst nicht mehr** so viel Einfluss wie früher, Mama.

> Sie haben das **längst nicht mehr** unter Kontrolle, oder?

One gets the feeling that there is a subtlety here that I am missing, otherwise, why not just use "lange nicht mehr" all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **längs** Präp. Adv. ‘an etw. entlang, der Länge nach’, ... frühnhd. auch *längst* (**mit hinzugetretenem t, s. unten**) sind **adverbiale Genitive Sing. des Adjektivs**. Das Adverb ist in der Gegenwart kaum noch in Gebrauch (etw. längs schneiden, nordd. längs kommen); als Präp. wird *längs* seit dem 14. Jh. verwendet.

> **längst** Adv. **‘seit langer Zeit, schon lange, bei weitem’**, frühnhd. *längst*, auch *langest, leng(e)st*. **Ursprünglich identisch mit *längs*** (s. oben), dessen adverbiale Verwendung im Sinne von ‘vor langer Zeit’ die durch sekundäres -t erweiterte Form übernimmt; entsprechend **unlängst** Adv. ‘vor nicht langer Zeit, vor kurzem’, ...

<sub>„lang“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al., Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993), im Digitalen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/lang -- emphasis mine, @vectory</sub>

That the *-t* is a mere phonetic outcrop (excrescence) is plausible. Conversely, final *-t* is often dropped, compare *nicht*, *nich'* "not", or affricated and velarised, cp. *nichts, nischt, nix* "naught".

Nevertheless, *-st* may be understood as superlative (as indicated by subordinate *wie früher* in collocation: “längst nicht mehr so viel wie früher”), or intensive (e.g. "by far" as suggested in comments, or "for the longest time", I guess: “Sie haben das längst nicht mehr unter Kontrolle”). Translation depends on context.

Note:

- a) the adverb is similar in formation to *bereit-s*, *nie-mal-s*, *jedenfalls* (cp. *anyway(s)*), differently *jetz', jetze, jetzt* (cf. *ie-zuo*, [difficult to explain](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/75135/35977)),
- b) the meaning may be influenced quite early by *Lenz* “springtime” (which is related to *lang*, cf. DWDS), like *früh* "early" as in *Frühjahr* "springtime" or indeed *ost, austro-* as in *Oster(n)* "easter" (I guess),
- c) the excrescent -t is also reminiscent of *letzt* “last, latest", itself related to *lassen* "let", see also *letztens* "some time ago, last time", *letzten Endes* "eventually", *zuletzt* "at the latest",
- d) *-n-* may be excrescent in this view as well, cf. *Dienstag* from Low German instead of Bavarian *Ziestag* “Tuesday, *Dies Jupiter*"
- e) exhortative?

The formation of adverbs with *-e* is still productive in a closed class of adjectives. It's quite messy: [Hatte die Deutsche Sprache einst Adverbien wie im Englischen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/hatte-die-deutsche-sprache-einst-adverbien-wie-im-englischen/73610#73610). See also in Dutch: **bij lange na niet**, meaning ca. "not in the least, not nearly" or "not like that" (“niet in het minst", "in het geheel niet", Philippa et al. via etymologiebank.nl).

That these could be inflected for case like a noun is not observed in the modern language. Any lexicalised difference is purely idiomatic.

Therefore no notable grammatical difference exists between *längst / lange nicht*. It is simply an intensive preposition with an adverbial head.

Comment: Wonderful! You bring the language alive. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*längst* means the same as *schon lange* (here) - *for a long time* in English.

Comment: While that is true  in general, in the case of the example given in the question, _längst_ means "by far". I think, your answer is wrong.

Comment: No, *längst* is a temporal reference, not quantitative.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach *Nicht mehr* in beiden Sätzen und *wie früher* im ersten weisen eindeutig auf eine temporale Bedeutung hin. Die Bedeutung "bei weitem" ["by far"] entsteht vor allem im synchronen Gebrauch (z.B. *[Hier ist es längst nicht so schön wie zu Hause](https://www.dwds.de/wb/l%C3%A4ngst)*). Man könnte allerding annehmen, dass *so viel* im ersten Satz eine zeitliche und räumliche Mischbedeutung bewirkt. Nichtsdestotrotz ist auch im ersten Satz die zeitliche Bedeutung mit vorhanden.

Comment: @Zac67 It can be argued that in the first example *längst* also has a quantitative meaning because of *so viel*.